# (iOS / CoreBluetooth) Identify corresponding "writeValue" call in "didUpdateValueFor"

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

**Context**

My peripheral has a characteristic which is used for sending commands but also for reading different values by sending **write commands**.
You can interpret these commands as I would say...

... *"Hey peripheral, next time I read your characteristic xyz I am interested in the following attribute..."*

Example workflow on that characteristic is:

1. Send **read** command by using `peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)`
2. Retrieve response of read command by calling `peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)`
3. Reading value of the characteristic in callback `peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)`. This is my response I have to validate. Here I need to identify what command I did send in 1). But since the characteristic is always the same and also the characteristics value does not give a hint on the previous write I have no clue how to deal with this.

**Question**

> **How can I match the events I receive in `didUpdateValueFor` to the initial "write" call?**

What I thought about as solution:

- Create a simple FIFO queue but I guess I can't rely on the call order and this also does not handle possible error cases (write did fail)
- Making the whole process synchronous (maybe by using `actor` with Swift 5.5?) but I guess this would give me other drawbacks concerning notify values from other characteristics...

Cheers 
Orlando

Comment: Your first thought is correct. Make a FIFO queue. You can rely on call order because you will send the commands FIFO; depending on the other side's software, you probably will want to wait for the response before sending another command. And you will handle error cases by watching for write errors (you'll get a delegate callback) and handling them. Typically in these kinds of protocols, there is some kind of "message id" that is attached to each message and response for correlation, but that has to be done in your protocol. Bluetooth itself offers you nothing here if you use it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will try it with the Queue but I still hope there is a more elegant approach. 